# Can I made vimrc config valid for some type of files and invalid for others?

Tags: vim

I'm a python programer. And I added these two line in my vimrc:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=grey guibg=grey
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

which will highlight the redundant spaces at the end of line with grey.

But recently I'm starting to write `md` docs. It's soft break requires two spaces at the end of line.

Thus my vimrc config makes these `md` docs less readable in editing stage.

Is there a way that some vimrc config can working selectively only for some kind of file, or be forbiddened when editing a particular kind of file?

Comment: For python you can do something like this `autocmd Filetype python setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4` note the `Filetype python` here

Comment: My [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) allows exceptions in the highlighting pattern, and does have such for the `markdown` filetype.